# In iOS devices, While opening a content in WebView getting _userSettingsForUser mobile

Tags: ios, webview, ios12

In iOS Devices, From iOS 12.2, While opening content in WebView, it is throwing the below lines in the console.

````
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    noOverridingAllowed = 1;
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO*```

Due to this, the content is loaded properly, so the buttons/redirections in the content are not working.

How to resolve it?
````

Answer (score -1):

This isn't an error but just a log. In order to wipe it, just set environment variable: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE to be "disable" inside Edit Scheme.

[image]